# Error: Subreport could not be shown. Sub Report works in Preview - but not when deployed

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a main report that runs multiple sub-reports. One of my sub reports runs perfectly fine in Preview, but when I deploy the report and run it from the browser, i simply get:

Error: Subreport could not be shown.

I've done some research and I am still not sure what the issue is. I've tried it in different browsers, my data sources for both the main report and sub report use the same shared data sources. And the main report and the parameters seem to pass fine (since it works in preview, I am assuming).

The error doesn't tell me much - has anyone else had this issue? Or any ideas how to debug? Many thanks!

Comment: Hi Mitch, could you elaborate a little bit? I'm just a beginner. The data sources have all been added on the report server if that is what you mean?

Comment: I hate to say I'm having the same issue...but I am.  I have two sub reports, both work by them selves.  Both work within the main report, in VS.  When I deploy all 3 reports, one sub report works, the other gets the ubiquitous "Error: Subreport could not be shown."  I've cleared cache, and still works locally.  I've cracked open the reports with XMLNotepad, and found no differences as to why one would work and the other not.  Both sub reports are passed the same parameters from the parent report, and call separate stored procedures to get data.  Why would it work local, and not on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue resolved. I needed to deploy my subreport as well, not just build.

Comment: I also had this issue happen when a subreport was re-named, yet it still worked in preview (Development) because the file was cached. Cleaning the environment might help for anyone else stuck with this error to give a better indication of the problem.

Comment: You just saved me hours upon hours @bschipp. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Check the parameters of the Sub Report. Correcting them appropriately will make it working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with multiples servers, be careful of where the datasets for all the sub reports are pointing to.